# How do I write this J Unit test properly? It fails even though the code works. What am I missing?

Tags: angularjs, jakarta-ee, junit4, rest-assured

This is my first attempt at unit testing. The project is AngularJS/JavaEE. The REST calls are coded in Java. The method I am attempting to test returns emails from a GMail inbox. The emails return ok in JSON format and Google console confirms that a status 200 has been returned, however when I test if JSON is returned along with a status 200, it fails on both counts.

Here is the REST class:

```
@GET
@Path("/get")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getInbox(@Context HttpServletRequest req)
        throws ServletException, IOException, JSONException {

    HttpSession session = req.getSession();

    Credential credential = (Credential) session.getAttribute("credential");

    Gmail service = new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY,
            credential).setApplicationName("Senior Mail").build();

    ArrayList<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
    ids.add("INBOX");

    JSONObject ticketDetails = new JSONObject();
    ListMessagesResponse openMessages = service.users().messages()
            .list("me").setLabelIds(ids).setMaxResults(new Long(maxEmails)).execute();

    List<com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Message> messages = openMessages
            .getMessages();

    JSONArray openTickets = new JSONArray();

    if (messages != null) {

        for (com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Message message : messages) {

            openTickets.add(getBareGmailMessageDetails(message.getId(),
                    credential));
        }
        ticketDetails.put("openTicketDetails", openTickets);
    }
    return Response.status(200).entity("" + ticketDetails.toJSONString()).build(); 

}
```

Here is the test using RestAssured:

```
import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.expect;
```

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured;
import com.jayway.restassured.http.ContentType;

public class InboxTest {

```
@Before
public void setUp(){
    RestAssured.basePath = "http://localhost:8080/resources";
}

@Test
public void testGetProducts(){
    expect().statusCode(200).contentType(ContentType.JSON).when()
            .get("/inbox/get");
}
```

}

And here is the test result:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 2 expectations failed.
```

Expected status code <200> doesn't match actual status code <400>.

Expected content-type "JSON" doesn't match actual content-type "".

```
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.doConstructorInvoke(CachedConstructor.java:71)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrap.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:81)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:57)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:190)
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure.validate(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:436)
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure$validate$1.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeFilterChain(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:774)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1085)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:730)
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1230)
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.this$2$applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1085)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:730)
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:136)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1085)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:730)
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.get(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:241)
at com.mail.senior.test.InboxTest.testGetProducts(InboxTest.java:22)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not actually having used this rest-testing-framework myself, looking at the examples found on their github repo I would try adding an "and()" between the two separate checks:

```
expect().statusCode(200).and().contentType(ContentType.JSON).when().get("/inbox/get")
```

Comment: Doesn't make any difference. Still same response. Making the actual REST call takes approx 5 seconds to return emails to the inbox, however J Unit test responds instantly. It doesn't wait to get the actual response.

Comment: I think its because the request needs to be authorized using OAuth 2. Even after I sign in with Google, the JUnit test call is unauthorised returning a 401 error.